# Часы html + js время Амстердам

Tags: javascript, html

```
как установить время страны Амстердам

https://codepen.io/yumeeeei/pen/qRwOOb
```

Comment: никто не овечает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: все зависит от серверного времени. Пожалуйста, скажите, какой используете серевер?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Defint the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Define some size
var radius = canvas.height / 2;

// Center the ctx
ctx.translate(radius,radius);

// Draw the Clock every second
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

// Draw the Clock 
function drawClock() {
 drawFace(ctx, radius);
 drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
 drawTime(ctx,radius);
 drawNose(ctx,radius);
}

// Define how to draw the Face
function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#F8F8FF";
 ctx.fill();
}

// Define how to draw the Numbers
function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
 var ang;
 var num;
 
 // Define the text styles
 ctx.font = "14px 'Lato'";
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";
 
 // Rotate and put number and rotate back
 for(num=1; num<=12; num++) {
  ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
  ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
 }
}

// Draw the Hands depends on current time
function drawTime(ctx,radius) {
// Get the current time
// create Date object for current location
var date = new Date();

// convert to milliseconds, add local time zone offset and get UTC time in milliseconds
var utcTime = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

// time offset for Amsterdam is +1
var timeOffset = +1;

// create new Date object for a different timezone using supplied its GMT offset.
var amsterdamTime = new Date(utcTime + (3600000 * timeOffset));
 
 var now = amsterdamTime;
 var hour = now.getHours();
 var minute = now.getMinutes();
 var second = now.getSeconds();
 
 // Draw the Hour Hand
 hour=hour%12;
 hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+(minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+(second*Math.PI/(360*60));
 drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.4, 4, "black");
 // Draw the Minute Hand
 minute=(minute*Math.PI/(30))+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
 drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.6, 2, "black");
 // Draw the Second Hand
 second=(second*Math.PI/30);
 drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.75, 1, "#DC143C");
}

// Define how to draw the Hands
function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width, color){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth = width;
 ctx.lineCap = "round";
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.rotate(pos);
 ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
 ctx.strokeStyle = color;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

function drawNose(ctx, radius) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*.08, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#DC143C";
 ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100')
 
html
body
.flex-container
 width 100%
 height 100%

.flex-container
 display flex
 justify-content center
 align-items center
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <canvas id="clock" width="240" height="240"></canvas>
</div>
```